# How do I properly call multiple functions in componentDidMount?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to call two different functions to display data on my page and one is working (getUserscards) and the second one is not (getUserInfo). I saw that you can put two different function calls for the data in componentDidMount and I have tried doing it several ways but the data for the email and names is not showing up. I will include the code from my profilepage where the componentDidMount is and from my api page where the function is made.

Here is my code in profilepage. js:

```
import React from 'react'
import { getUsersCards, getUsersInfo } from '../Api'

class ProfilePage extends React.Component {
  constructor () {
    super()
    this.state = {
      token: window.localStorage.getItem('login_auth_token'),
      username: localStorage.getItem('login_username') || '',
      email: '',
      first_name: '',
      last_name: '',
      cards: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    if (this.state.token) {
      getUsersCards(this.state.token)
        .then(cards => this.setState({ cards: cards }))
    }
    getUsersInfo(this.state.email, this.state.first_name, this.state.last_name)
      .then(data => this.setState({ data: data }))
  }

  componentDidUpdate (prevProps, prevState) {
    if (this.state.token && this.state.token !== prevState.token) {
      getUsersCards(this.state.token).then(cards => this.setState({ cards: cards }))
    }
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className='container2'>
          <div>
            <p>Username: {this.state.username}</p>
          </div>
          <div>
          Email: {this.state.email}
          </div>
          <div>
            <p>Name: {this.state.first_name}{this.state.last_name}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          {this.state.cards.map(card => <p className='container' key={card.id}> Title: {card.card_name}  <br />  Card: {card.card_text}</p>)}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default ProfilePage
```

And here is the function from my api.js page:

```
export function getUsersInfo (token) {
  return request.get('/users/info', {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Token ${token}`
    }
  }).then(res => {
    console.log(res.data)
    return res.data
  })
}
```

Comment: It looks like the `getUsersInfo()` function expects a token, whereas in `componentDidMount` you are sending `getUsersInfo(email, fname, lname)`.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is, when you call `this.setState({ data: data })`, in your state **MUST HAVE** a key `data`.

Maybe change into this may help

`this.setState({ email: data.email, first_name: data.first_name, last_name: data.last_name })`

Just need the exactly key to work

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I tried it but sadly it didn't work. Maybe I need to change something else as well. Thank you again. I will look further

Comment: You can check `getUsersInfo` function again, it receives only ONE param is `token`. And please make sure it return all info you need (email, first_name, last_name).

Comment: Nice to hear that :)

Answer (score 0):

the problem is likely here,

```
export function getUsersInfo (token) {
  return request.get('/users/info', {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Token ${token}`
    }
  }).then(res => {
    console.log(res.data)
    return res.data //!! note
  })
}
```

You are returning raw data from the server when are you parsing it to `json`, YOu Must parse it somehow to make is object so you can use.

Comment: I don't know because I am getting my card data that exact way and it works

Comment: which package yourr using for the request??  can you provide your code in any kind of sandbox??